# What is the best approach to do fsck on corrupted disk + redhat 7

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, redhat-enterprise-linux, fsck

What is the best approach to do fsck on corrupted disk

- one from the following options:

The first option is to set “1”  ( the last character ) on device in /etc/fstab file   ,

so it will check this partition first , as the following example:

```
 /dev/sdc /grop/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1   <-------- < we set 1 instead 0 >
```

and then **reboot** machine

- during boot fsck will run on device /dev/sdc

The second approach , is to do the following

```
init 1
stop the relevant services
umount /dev/sdc
e2fsck -y /dev/sdc
init 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't call `init 1` on a remote machine!** or you'll be locked out.

If the disk is really corrupted, I won't trust fsck running alone at boot.

If the machine is a **local** machine, I would recommend your `init 1` method, then reboot.

If the machine is **remote** machine.

- Stop all services one at a time, **not stopping ssh**, until the `umount /dev/sdc` command succeed.
- Fix the disk using `e2fsck`.
- remount it to be sure it is really fine (`mount -a`).
- `reboot`. Since you've already stopped most useful services, this won't take so much more time to reboot. Generally, I install security updates just before rebooting, so I save the next reboot needed for security updates.